# How to get latest tag in github using git2go in Golang?

Tags: git, go, tags

I am trying to get the latest github tag from my local repository in golang.
For now I am getting all the tags, code is below:

```
repo, err := git.OpenRepository("/home/defiant/Temp/repo")
    checkErr(err)
    re, err := repo.Tags.List()
    checkErr(err)
    fmt.Println(re)
```

The result returned is of the format:

```
[0.1 1.3 1.4]
```

Here 1.3 is the latest tag. So can someone please help me out in getting only the latest tag?

Comment: Why is tag 1.3 newer than tag 1.4? That seems like more of an issue lmao

Comment: I was just trying out to know if the order of the tags are in the order at which it was created.

Comment: are there any properties of repo.Tags that have date or time or anything?

Comment: I dont think so, I think we can get the dates and times by using logs option in git command.

Comment: you need to to get the tag commits with their dates. Then order by date, for the particular case you presented. For a semver ordering, see https://github.com/Masterminds/semver. Not sure how git2go can help you to get tag commits.

Comment: I used os.command to run git describe to get the latest tags.

Answer (score 0):

The bit you are looking for is the `signature` object (it has a `when` field). On a commit, you might be interested in either the `author` or the `committer`. If you are using `annotated` tags themselves - they have the `tagger` field which is when the commit was tagged.

If you have only annotated tags (i.e. no lightweight) this should get you the timestamps for the tags:

```golang
repo, err := git.OpenRepository("/home/defiant/Temp/repo")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = repo.Tags.Foreach(func(name string, id *git.Oid) error {
    tag, err := repo.LookupTag(id)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    log.Info(tag.Tagger().When)
    return nil
})
```

Working with lightweight tags you will need to resolve the commit directly - you should be able to do this with `LookupCommit` and explicitly choose the `committer` or the `author`.